# is there a way to create a 360 animation movie (equirectangular) with paraview?

Tags: 3d, paraview, 360-degrees

I would like to create a 360 animation (equirectangular, for [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAc_hF_RKkY)) using Paraview. I have already tried to export my data to other softwares like Blender with no success.

Any helps?
thanks!

ps.
the idea is to generate some animations for a scientific YouTube channel

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you have already tried something, please show us so that we can help you with your mistakes instead of writing something from scratch. Best regards.

Comment: Hello @caser, have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an camera animation to *orbit* a dataset. See this [wiki page](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Animating_the_Camera) for details. The Wiki is a little old, the part about *Revolving around an object of interest* is still relevant (as of ParaView 5.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible with ParaView 5.7 using the "Panoramic View Plugin".
It supports equirectangular and azimuthal equidistant projection.
Have a look at https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/merge_requests/2798